# Abp 'FeatureManagementPermissions' does not exist in the current context

Tags: abp

I am using [Abp](https://github.com/abpframework/abp) and I run app project from template folder. It works perfectly but I have had a problem with tenant section. In fact, when I clicked on tenants management sections, I got this error

```
abp\modules\tenant-management\src\Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.Web\Pages\TenantManagement\Tenants\Index.cshtml

The name 'FeatureManagementPermissions' does not exist in the current context
+
@if (await Authorization.IsGrantedAsync(FeatureManagementPermissions.ManageHostFeatures))
```

Answer (score 1):

I should try run build-all.ps1 .
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/build/build-all.ps1